# JQUERY Selecting nth list element across multiple unordered lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

Unfortunately, this can't be done with pure css because nth-of-type only selects on relation to an element's parent ([w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp)). So I'm looking for a jquery alternative that works across multiple lists.

HTML:

```
<div class="container" id="videos">
   <ul class="thumbnails">
      <li class="tn">
         <img class="tn-img" src="img/thumbnails/placeholder.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li class="tn">
         <img class="tn-img" src="img/thumbnails/placeholder.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li class="tn">
         <img class="tn-img" src="img/thumbnails/placeholder.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li class="tn">
         <img class="tn-img" src="img/thumbnails/placeholder.jpg" />
      </li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="thumbnails">
      <li class="tn">
         <img class="tn-img" src="img/thumbnails/placeholder.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li class="tn">
         <img class="tn-img" src="img/thumbnails/placeholder.jpg" />
      </li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="thumbnails">
      <li class="tn">
         <img class="tn-img" src="img/thumbnails/placeholder.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li class="tn">
         <img class="tn-img" src="img/thumbnails/placeholder.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li class="tn">
         <img class="tn-img" src="img/thumbnails/placeholder.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li class="tn">
         <img class="tn-img" src="img/thumbnails/placeholder.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li class="tn">
         <img class="tn-img" src="img/thumbnails/placeholder.jpg" />
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$( "#videos li:nth-of-type(5n+1) img" ).css( "margin-left" , "0px");
```

This code is still selecting :nth-of-type(5n+1) in relation to it's parent (the unordered list). I can tell because the first list item in every ul is being selected. I need to select the 5th list item across every unordered list, disregarding it's parent.

Comment: What exactly is not working in your case? Or your question?

Comment: I think you don't need to use jQuery for this purpose, use CSS instead..

Comment: Syntax error in `.css( "margin-left":"0px")`. Should be `.css( "margin-left","0px")` or `.css( {"margin-left":"0px"})`

Comment: Fixed the syntax error. But it's still selecting :nth-of-type(5n+1) in relation to it's parent (the unordered list). I can tell because the first list item in every ul is being selected.

Comment: So just get all the `li`, loop over them, and do whatever you want to do only to every fifth of them by increasing a counter …

Comment: … or, instead of looping over them, use `.eq()` to access the fifth, 10th … etc. element directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var items = $('#videos li'),
    counter = 0, // first element, counting starts at zero
    step = 5,
    item = null;

while((item = items.eq(counter)).length) {
    item.addClass('special'); // or do whatever else with it
    counter += step;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1573ahug/

---

Edit: Or, via a good ol’ `for` loop (that way we don’t have to call `.length` so often to see whether there are actually still elements):

```
var items = $('#videos li'),
    start = 0, // first element, counting starts at zero
    step = 5;

for(var i=start, l=items.length; i<l; i+=step) {
    items.eq(i).addClass('special');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1573ahug/1/

Answer (score -1):

The structure of your .css() was in the wrong format. ( had a : instead of a , )  Also, the selector wasn't working, not sure why the selector wasn't working the way you had it, but this should work.

```
$( "#videos li:nth-of-type(5n+1)" ).find('img').css( "margin-left","0px");
```